# How to use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() to save an image?

Tags: python, python-requests, permission-denied, temporary-files

I am trying to a write a code in Python that will get a picture of a dashboard in tableau and send it to a slack channel.
first part works perfectly and saves the image to my local laptop. But when trying to save the image in a temp path and send it to a channel I get the error:

```
---> 45 f = {'file': (temp_file.name, open(temp_file.name, 'rb'), 'png')} 

46 response = requests.post(url='slack./com/api/files.upload', data= 47 {'token': bot_token, 'channels': slack_channels, 'media': f,'initial_comment' :''}, 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Userlogin-~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp3fzm10gj.png'
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests 
from slack import WebClient
    
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
    
import tableauserverclient as TSC
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_views_dataframe, get_view_data_dataframe

req_option = TSC.RequestOptions().page_size(1000)
image_req_option = TSC.ImageRequestOptions(imageresolution=TSC.ImageRequestOptions.Resolution.High)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get(req_option)
    workbook_id_ = [workbook.id for workbook in all_workbooks if workbook.name == workbook_name][0]
    workbook = server.workbooks.get_by_id(workbook_id_)
    all_views= workbook.views

    for view_item in all_views:
        if view_item.name == view_name:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png', delete=True) as temp_file:
                server.views.populate_image(view_item, req_options=image_req_option)
                temp_file.write(view_item.image)
                print('image is created')
                # I get the error after the print
                f = {'file': (temp_file.name, open(temp_file.name, 'rb'), 'png')}
                response = requests.post(url='https://slack./com/api/files.upload', data=
                           {'token': bot_token, 'channels': slack_channels, 'media': f, 'initial_comment' :''},
                           headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, files=f)
                print('the image is in the channel')
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of the stack trace containing all of the error details? And when you say "I get the error in after the print" do you mean to say the error before the print right above the comment or after the last print statement? Also what imports do you have here? I am familiar with `requests` but what is TSC? Also is it supposed to be `slack.com` not slack./om`?

Comment: And if you save bytes as a temporary file but plan to then read it back, make sure you use `mode='wb+'`. I think that is the default but might want to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to re-open an already opened file here:

```py
f = {'file': (temp_file.name, open(temp_file.name, 'rb'), 'png')}
```

Try instead:

```py
temp_file.file.seek(0)  # change the position to the beginning of the file
f = {'file': (temp_file.name, temp_file, 'png')}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried changing the position but now getting another error:
```
`ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='slack.', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /com/api/files.upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000180D4DDAEB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))`
```
Also, I am not sure if the image is actially being saved to a tempfile. Is there a way to check it ?

Comment: @bigsbi yes, if you pass `delete=False` to `NamedTemporaryFile` the file will not be deleted after exiting the context manager.

I believe there is an error in the URL 'https://slack./com/api/files.upload', maybe it should be 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload'?